# Upload a remote photo to another server

Tags: php

I create script for upload photo from server to another server.

```
$file_name_with_full_path = realpath("imgs/classified/imgname.jpg");
$postimg = array('myfile'=>'@'.$file_name_with_full_path);
```

I tested this script on localhost. It's working. But I tested on my server. It's not working.

This's full path of photo from server when I echo realpath.

```
/home/admin/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/autopost/imgs/classified/imagename.jpg
```

It not have error.

Comment: has php user write rights in the folder? does the folder exisits?

Comment: @donald123 Yes, the folder is exisits.